# update table (select) sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  problem in the sql I want to update the table 
This is my query

```
update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 AS "Total Cost" FROM  TICKET) from ticket
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB0R6.png)

Comment: i can't open image can you explain your problem with your comments ?

Comment: the added photo is opened?

Comment: what is the logic when the foiz_sub equal null . Are you considering as a 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more breifly

Comment: I consider as 0, but this is not important, since in id_T 23031 has a foiz_sub

Comment: You can try this `update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select (case foiz_sub is null then 0 else foiz_sub end ) * tarif_som / 100 AS "Total Cost" FROM TICKET) from TICKET`

Comment: I want to multiply foiz_sub and tarif_som and to update voz_sub_som

Comment: OK then you can try `update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select (case foiz_sub is null then 0 else foiz_sub end ) * tarif_som  FROM TICKET)`

Comment: Harun, put the code in the sql error. <Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.>

Comment: I don't have the schema thats why i cant put the code in sql  . I updated latest code

Comment: Harun, did so but still bugger
update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 FROM TICKET) from TICKET

<Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.> what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this**

```
 update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 AS "Total Cost" FROM  TICKET)
```